# ctrl+shift not working in kubuntu 17.10 in this last days

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice

Only in my user session in LibreOffice and in any other apps **"shift+ctrl+[some key]"** **does not work**: e.g. "shift+ctrl+left" does not select the word on the left. I can select the word lettere per letter, using "shift+left"

As other user instead I can use shift+ctrl+[some key].

So the problem is something in my home configuration: but what?

I tried renaming the khotkeysrc and kglobalshortcutsrc files, but nothing to do

Thank you

Comment: Renaming the file kxkbrc (in .config) seemed to work at first, but then enough, the problem continues

Comment: Solved creating a new user.

Comment: No: not solved; after new user creation the problem rise again.

Comment: The strange is that now I have this problem with the new user (with the old name), while with the old user (with new name) the prolem is fixed

Comment: New installation of Kubuntu: still the same problem!

Comment: This is the result of env: '~$ xev | sed -n 's/^.*state \([0-9].*\), keycode *\([0-9]\+\) *\(.*\), .*$/keycode \2 = \3, state = \1/p'
keycode 36 = (keysym 0xff0d, Return), state = 0x10
keycode 37 = (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), state = 0x10
keycode 50 = (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), state = 0x14
keycode 37 = (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), state = 0x10
keycode 50 = (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), state = 0x14
keycode 37 = (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), state = 0x15
keycode 50 = (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), state = 0x11'

Comment: Disconnected Clementine (previoulsy shared) settings: problem solved! Incredible, but true.

Answer (score 0):

It is known [bug 1720364](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1720364). I created [`ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys`](https://launchpad.net/~nrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys) with patched Xorg.

You can join conversation on [community.ubuntu.com](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876).

Comment: Thank you but maybe it's not my case: 1) I don't use ctrl+shift for switching keyboard, 2) the probleme is only in my user session, not as other user, 3) the problem appaears only in this last days. Anyway where is your PPA (does it works?).